# Django custom Auth form. How to show error messages

Tags: django, django-forms

Another Django form question -.-
So, I have this form which works just fine, but it won't show any error messages. I'm pretty new to customising forms, so my question is that, do I need to specify anything else in order for my messages to show up?
Forms.py file

```
class UserLoginForm(AuthenticationForm):
error_css_class = "error"
def __init__(self,*args,**kwargs):
    super(UserLoginForm, self).__init__(*args,**kwargs)

username = forms.CharField(widget=forms.TextInput(
    attrs={'class': 'input','placeholder': 'Username','label':''}
))
password = forms.CharField(widget=forms.PasswordInput(
    attrs={'class': 'input','placeholder': 'Password','label':''}
))
```

HTML File:

```
{%block content%}
    <form class="form" method="POST">
        {% csrf_token %} 
        <fieldset class="form-group text-center text-uppercase">
            <h1 class="sign-in__header">Sign up</h1>
            {% for field in form %}
                <p>
                    
                    {{ field }}
                    {{ field.help_text }}
                </p>
            {% endfor %}
        </fieldset>
        <div class="form-group">
            <button class="submit" type="submit">Sign in</button>
        </div>
        {% for field in form %}
            <div>{{ field.errors}}</div>
        {% endfor %}
        </div>
    </form>
        
        </div>
    {%endblock content%}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you remain on the same view when the form is not valid then in template you can access this errors by passing them to your view like this .

```
def View(request):
    form = myForm(request.POST)
    if form.is_valid():
       return HttpResponseRedirect('/yourview/')
    return render(request, 'template.html', {'form': form})
```

**then in template**

```
{% if form.errors %}
    {% for field in form %}
        {% for error in field.errors %}
            <div class="alert alert-danger">
                <strong>{{ error|escape }}</strong>
            </div>
        {% endfor %}
    {% endfor %}
    {% for error in form.non_field_errors %}
        <div class="alert alert-danger">
            <strong>{{ error|escape }}</strong>
        </div>
    {% endfor %}
{% endif %}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
{% if form.errors %}
{% for field in form %}
    {% for error in field.errors %}
        <p> {{ error }} </p>
    {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
{% endif %}
```